# Prevent InvalidOperationException when using ToTask on IObservable

Tags: c#, task, observable, system.reactive

I need to somehow prevent the `InvalidOperationException` which is thrown when calling ToTask on an Observable which does not produce any values.

What i have seen is that the ToTask method creates an instance of the `ToTaskObserver` and it wants at least one value to not throw an exception:

```cs
private sealed class ToTaskObserver<TResult> : SafeObserver<TResult>
{
    //[...]
    private bool _hasValue;
    private TResult _lastValue;

    public ToTaskObserver(TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs, CancellationToken ct)
    {
       //[...]
    }

    public override void OnNext(TResult value)
    {
       _hasValue = true;
       _lastValue = value;
    }

    //[...]

    public override void OnCompleted()
    {
        if (_hasValue)
        {
            _tcs.TrySetResult(_lastValue);
        }
        else
        {
           _tcs.TrySetException(new InvalidOperationException(Strings_Linq.NO_ELEMENTS));
        }
        //[...]
    }
    //[...]
}
```

The only solution i have found is to mimic the extension method and inject a dummy record into the Observable through a merge:

```cs
public static Task<Record<TKey, TValue>> ToTask<TKey, TValue>(
    this IObservable<Record<TKey, TValue>> source, CancellationToken token)
{
   var pseudoObservable = new[] {Record.Create<TKey, TValue>(default, default)}.ToObservable();
   return source.Merge(pseudoObservable).ToTask(token);
}
```

This question is especially about the `ToTask` method. I know that when i would use the `Subscribe` method i wouldn't have that problem.

Does someone has a better solution for this? I have scenarios where my observable will not have any records.

Comment: Why are you mixing Rx and Tasks? And why are you writing your own implementation of `IObservable<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

A number of options here:

- If you are expecting multiple records (and you probably aren't because awaiting those doesn't work well), then you can use `.ToList()`.
- If you're expecting 0 or 1 records, and `default(T)` isn't a valid value, you can use `.LastOrDefaultAsync()`, then checking for the default value.
- If you're expecting 0 or 1 records and `default(T)` is a valid value, you could still use `.ToList()`, or you could use an `Option` style class:

An `Option` class would look like this, unless I'm forgetting about a built-in option for C# (F# has one).

```
public class Optional<T>
{
    private readonly bool _hasValue;
    private readonly T _value;
    public Optional(T t)
    {
        _value = t;
        _hasValue = true;
    }

    public Optional()
    {
        _hasValue = false;
        _value = default(T);
    }

    public bool HasValue => _hasValue;
    public T Value 
    {
        get 
        {
            if(HasValue)
                return _value;
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No value present");
        }
    }
}

public static class X { 
    public static IObservable<Optional<T>> ToOptional<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
    {
        return source.Publish(_source => _source
            .Select(t => new Optional<T>(t))
            .LastOrDefaultAsync()
            .Select(n => n.Equals(default(Optional<T>)) ? new Optional<T>() : n)
        );
    }
}
```

I prefer the `Optional` option over `List`, because `List` looks funny when you know there's a max of one value. But up to you. Here's sample use:

```
var fortyTwoList = await Observable.Return(42).ToList();
var noneList = await Observable.Empty<int>().ToList();
var fortyTwo = await Observable.Return(42).ToOptional();
var none = await Observable.Empty<int>().ToOptional();

none.Dump();        //Linqpad
fortyTwo.Dump();    //Linqpad
noneList.Dump();        //Linqpad
fortyTwoList.Dump();    //Linqpad
```

Comment: my normal use case is to expect more than one value. I'm consuming messages from kafka and i have implemented some kind of a snapshot feature where i only process messages between specific offsets. It can happen that when my consumer starts it has already read to the end of the topic and therefore have no messages, resulting in the exception.

Comment: Oh. If you're not interested in the values, then any of these options will work. I would recommend `.LastOrDefaultAsync()`.